# JSON array retrieve value by name

Tags: android, json

```
public void onResponse( String response ){
    JSONArray jsonArray ;
    try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
        String result = jsonObject.getString("name");
        t.setText(result);
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and my json file is

```
[  
{  
  "0":"1",
  "1":"Adarsh",
  "id":"1",
  "name":"Adarsh"
},
{  
  "0":"2",
  "1":"Asif",
  "id":"2",
  "name":"Asif"
},
{  
  "0":"3",
  "1":"Baba",
  "id":"3",
  "name":"Baba"
},
{  
  "0":"4",
  "1":"Beeta",
  "id":"4",
  "name":"Beeta"
}
]
```

In my application it doesn't retrieve the value for "name" instead showing error toast.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: You are getting a string response. Get a JsonResponse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsonArray has not been initialised

```
jsonArray = new JSONArray("yourjson");

String name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1).getString("name");
```

Comment: I had...just need some more reputation to be visible

Answer (score 0):

First change your string response to json response like this:

```
JsonArray jarray=new JsonArray(response); 
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
String result = jsonObject.getString("name");
t.setText(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to fetch data from string as per your comment so need to convert in to json first like this

```
public void onResponse( String response ){
   try{
     JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(response);
     Log.d("JsonArray", jsonArray.toString());
     JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
     String result = jsonObject.getString("name");
     t.setText(result);
  }
  catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e("ERROR", "Wrong Json format");
  }
  catch(JSONException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```